# How to hide the facebox header for that particular facebox?

Tags: jquery, facebox

how can i hide the particular header for the facebox, without disturbing the default method

```
function creatappstack(){
    jQuery.facebox({
        ajax: 'CreateAppStack.action'
    });
    if($('#pop_title').html("")){
        $("#pop_title").parent().css('display','none'); 
    }

}
```

the above code is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
if($('#pop_title').html() == ""){
```

instead of:

```
if($('#pop_title').html("")){
```

Comment: tried that too but not working.. any default method or function i can use??

Comment: I'm not sure about this but you can go through some events which are quite useful as I can see from their docs: https://github.com/defunkt/facebox#events

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the iFrame version of the Likebox (facebox) you can add this to the SRC url:

```
&header=false
```

If you are using another version, say the HTML5 version, you can use the attribute data-header. Like so:

```
data-header="false"
```

It is almost impossible to fix this through jQuery or JavaScript, because the like box will always be iFramed and the contents are hosted by Facebook. More information about the like box and his settings, you can find here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages